# Question on Gorenstein projective modules

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Call a finite dimensional algebra $A$ special in case the category of (finite dimensional) Gorenstein projective modules coincides with the category of finite dimensional modules $M$ such that $Ext^i(M,A)=0$ for all $i \geq 1$.

Questions:

1. If $A$ is special, is the enveloping algebra $A \otimes_k A^{op}$ also special?
2. If $A^e$ is special, is $A$ special?
3. Is there an easy example such that $A$ is not Gorenstein and $A$ and $A^e$ are special?